# Porting apply() from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, apply, porting

I'm migrating some legacy python2 code to python3, and came across this function:

```
FRAMESTART_A = 231
FRAMETYPE_VIDEO = 6

def prepMessage(self, x):
        self.nextMessage = []
        bytes = []
        bytes.append(FRAMESTART_A)  # frame start
        bytes.append(FRAMETYPE_VIDEO)  # addresss
        for n in range(self.width):
            # set values from [0, width]
            value = 65535 * \
                (1.0 - (math.pow(0.5 * (math.sin(x / 2000 + time.time()) + 1), 4)))
            bytes.append(value)
        for n in range(50 - self.width):
            # set bytes from [width, :] to zero
            bytes.append(0)
        message = apply(struct.pack,["BB"+"H"*(len(bytes)-2)]+bytes)
        self.nextMessage.append(message)
```

Conceptually, I get that this is creating a byte array of items that's always 50 bytes long, with the last bytes padded to zero.  In Python3, `apply()` doesn't exist anymore, so the problem is with the line:

```
    message = apply(struct.pack,["BB"+"H"*(len(bytes)-2)]+bytes)
```

Reading the docs, it looks like I can just use the `*` operator to apply the function to a list of arguments, as so:

```
message = struct.pack(*(["BB" + "H" * (len(bytes) - 2)] + bytes))
```

But this produces a runtime error:

```
    message = struct.pack(*(["BB" + "H" * (len(bytes) - 2)] + bytes))
    struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Looking at the python3 `struct.pack` documentation, it looks like I should get input a formatting string that looks like "BBHHHHHHH..." and then give it the byte array.  However, the original code works!  So I'm not sure how `message = apply(struct.pack,["BB"+"H"*(len(bytes)-2)]+bytes)` worked, unless `struct.pack` worked substantially different in python2.

What's the right way to port this forward to get working code?

Comment: You can simplify it to just `struct.pack("BB" + "H" * (len(bytes) - 2), *bytes)`, though I don't think that fixes the error.

Comment: Also, I don't think `value` is used at all? Should that be replaced with `brightness`?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `bytes`?

Comment: You're right about the variable name, got mixed up in cleaning up the code for posting here...

Switching to `message = struct.pack(["BB" + "H" * (len(bytes) - 2)], *bytes)`
 just produces `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

The array should just be two header packets (FRAMESTARTA then FRAMETYPE_VIDEO) followed by 50 16-bit integers.

Comment: It should be ``struct.pack("BB" + "H" * (len(bytes) - 2), *bytes)``, not ``struct.pack(["BB" + "H" * (len(bytes) - 2)], *bytes)``. Note how there's no ``[`` ``]``.

Comment: That works!  Any idea why the old syntax worked?  It doesn't look sensible to me!

Comment: Since you're re-writing this, it'd be good to name your list of bytes to something else, since `bytes` is a builtin class type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recreate `apply` in Python 3, it's pretty easy:

```
def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
    return func(*args) if kwargs is None else func(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to make the code work on either Py2 or Py3, just put this at the top of your file to make a fallback `apply` when it's not provided:

```
try:
    apply
except NameError:
    def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
        return func(*args) if kwargs is None else func(*args, **kwargs)
```

That said, you don't really need `apply` either on Py2 or Py3; any time you see:

```
apply(somefunc, someargs)
```

like this, you can change it to just:

```
somefunc(*someargs)
```

so in this case, it would be:

```
message = struct.pack(*["BB"+"H"*(len(bytes)-2)]+bytes)
```

or even more simply (since concatenating one thing onto the front only to unpack immediately is unnecessary when you can just pass that one thing and unpack the rest without the extra temporary):

```
message = struct.pack("BB"+"H"*(len(bytes)-2), *bytes)
```